# Can I use Esri JavaScript Api with OGC Services from Open source Like QGis?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-js-api

Can I use Esri JavaScript Api with OGC Services from Opensource Like QGis?

Comment: When you refer to QGIS, you mean QGIS Server? .. or you mean, use OGC services like you use it from QGIS Desktop?

Comment: I mean any service that is ogc. I just want to know if i can use esri js api(all its features) with anyother gis services not just for esri. and if so is there any other libraries as good as this?  And yes i mean QGis Services Also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcGIS JavaScript 4 library supports several OGC standards, including WMS, WMTS, KML, and OGC API Features. WFS it is supported in version 3 but not yet supported in version 4, it is marked as coming soon although.

You can find much more information on the external data sources that are supported by the API in the documentation ([ArcGIS API - External data sources](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/layers-and-data/#working-with-external-data-sources)).

If you are only looking for a JavaScript library to work exclusively with OGC services, with that I mean you have no intention of using ArcGIS services, maybe you can go with [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org) of [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com). Both are major libraries with great communities behind. I would say that OpenLayers is more comparable to ArcGIS JS, in vast functionalities.

Anyways, which one to use depends of many factors, including requirements, expertise, budget, etc.